# Bot Discord does not recognize commands

Tags: python, discord

I am creating a bot for Discord in Python but when I want to get the commands to a separate class it doesn't recognize them anymore. When I had the commands in the 'main' it worked fine, in fact, the following commands work perfectly:

```py
        @self.bot.command()
        async def testGame(ctx):
            await ctx.send('Hola Mundo')

        @self.bot.command()
        async def sarasa(ctx):
            await ctx.send('saraasas asasa asasas')
```

The problem is that when I take the commands out of the main and pass them to an external class, the bot does not recognize them anymore.

My 'main' class is the following:

```py
import os
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # Leer el archivo de configuración
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        config_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'config.json')
        with open(config_path, "r") as f:
            config = json.load(f)
        self.token = config["TOKEN"]
        # Configurar los Intents
        all_intents = discord.Intents.all()
        self.bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=all_intents)
        print(f"Bot en Game: {self.bot}")

    def start_bot(self):
        # Cargar las extensiones (Cogs)
        cogs = ["modulos.comandos", "modulos.gptlogic", "modulos.test"]
        for cog in cogs:
            self.bot.load_extension(cog)
            print(f"{cog} ha sido agregado")

    @self.bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Bot is ready.")

    @self.bot.command()
    async def testGame(ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hola Mundo')

    @self.bot.command()
    async def sarasa(ctx):
        await ctx.send('saraasas asasa asasas')

        self.bot.run(self.token)
        print(f"Bot en start_bot: {self.bot}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.start_bot()
```

And my commands are in another class:

```py
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class comandos(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        """Comando de prueba que envía un mensaje de 'Hola Mundo'."""
        await ctx.send('Hola Mundo')

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def limpiar(self, ctx, cantidad: int = 100):
        """Comando que borra una cantidad de mensajes en el canal."""
        cantidad = min(max(1, cantidad), 1000)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=cantidad + 1)  # +1 para incluir el mensaje del comando
        msg = await ctx.send(f'{cantidad} mensajes han sido borrados.')
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await msg.delete()

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def anclar(self, ctx, mensaje_id: int):
        """Comando que ancla un mensaje en el canal."""
        try:
            mensaje = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(mensaje_id)
        except discord.NotFound:
            await ctx.send("No se pudo encontrar un mensaje con ese ID.")
            return
        await mensaje.pin()
        await ctx.send(f'El mensaje con ID {mensaje_id} ha sido anclado.')


    def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(comandos(bot))
```

The error i ger in the console is:

> Bot en Game: <discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot object at
> 0x000001C435FEA010>         modulos.comandos ha sido agregado
> modulos.gptlogic ha sido agregado         modulos.test ha sido
> agregado         2023-08-21 08:17:42 INFO discord.client logging in
> using static token         2023-08-21 08:17:43 INFO discord.gateway
> Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID:
> 86232757a52db9e5bb8a6abe6afc362b).         Bot is ready.
> 2023-08-21 08:18:02 ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception
> in command None         discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound:
> Command "test" is not found         2023-08-21 08:18:08 ERROR
> discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "limpiar" is not
> found

**Note**: I have the last stable version of both Python and Discord.

Comment: Main SO is in English only [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ifixit doing this:

```
import asyncio
import json
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from modulos.comandos import comandos
from modulos.gptlogic import gptlogic
from modulos.test import test

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # Leer el archivo de configuración
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        config_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'config.json')
        with open(config_path, "r") as f:
            config = json.load(f)

        self.token = config["TOKEN"]

        # Configurar los Intents
        all_intents = discord.Intents.all()
        self.bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=all_intents)

        print(f"Bot en Game: {self.bot}")

    async def start_bot(self):
        # Cargar las extensiones (Cogs)
        cogs = [comandos(self.bot), gptlogic(self.bot), test()]
        for cog in cogs:
            try:
                await self.bot.add_cog(cog)
                print(f"{cog} ha sido agregado")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"No se pudo cargar la extensión {cog}. Error: {e}")
        
        @self.bot.event
        async def on_ready():
            print("Bot is ready.")
    
        await self.bot.start(self.token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     game = Game()
     asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(game.start_bot())
```

Comment: The answer does not explain what the issue was in the question.